# Javascript - how to check if all RegExp are true?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a little problem.
this code is used as password validator.

classlist.add create checked icon when regexp return true.

How can I add a new class for all, when all regexp are true ?
Sorry for my English and thks for your help.

```
elf.controlPassword = function (event) {

    const lenthNoSpace = new RegExp(/^(\S{8,20})$/);
    const hasNumber = new RegExp(/\d+/);
    const hasUpperCaseLowerCase = new RegExp(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])/);
    const hasSpecialChar = new RegExp(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/);

    const value = event.target.value;

    toggleCheck(value, lenthNoSpace, validLenth);
    toggleCheck(value, hasNumber, validNumber);
    toggleCheck(value, hasUpperCaseLowerCase, validCase);
    toggleCheck(value, hasSpecialChar, validSpecialChar);
}

const toggleCheck = function (value, regex, display) {
    if (regex.test(value) === true) {
        display.classList.remove('icon-dot');
        display.classList.add('coucoutest');

        return 1;
    }
    else
  {
        display.classList.remove('coucoutest');
        display.classList.add('icon-dot');

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the results of all the `toggleCheck` calls into an array, then check that all values are 1:

```
const results = [
    toggleCheck(value, lenthNoSpace, validLenth),
    toggleCheck(value, hasNumber, validNumber),
    toggleCheck(value, hasUpperCaseLowerCase, validCase),
    toggleCheck(value, hasSpecialChar, validSpecialChar),
];
if (results.every(r => r === 1)) {
  for (const display of [validLenth, validNumber, validCase, validSpecialChar]) {
    display.classList.add('somethingWhenAllRegexPass');
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend

- Using proper spelling to avoid bugs - you probably want `length` instead of `lenth`
- Use more precise variable names - it sounds like `validNumber` and `validCase`, for example, are *elements*, which is not clear from their name

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :) 
I have just one problem. 
The Class add correctly, but if i want to remove it with Else, it doesn't work.

else {
          display.classList.remove('somethingWhenAllRegexPass');
        }